# Mac OS X Difference between actual and displayed space usage

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, disk-space

I checked my Macbook Air's disk usage with 'ncdu' tool and found that there is a big difference between my actual space usage and the displayed one. It has a 128 GB SSD and it's running OS X Mavericks [image: NCDU screenshot]

[image: System tool screenshot]

Is there any way to make the storage more compact and save that lost space? Or is it normal to have such a discrepancy in SSDs and/or Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you deleted the files, you may need to run the `sync` command in a terminal. Rebooting should do the same thing, only better (see the sync man page).

Comment: There was a big difference even before anything was deleted, i updated my question to avoid misleading people. And i rebooted at least a couple of times.